# Typed.js text animation pauses when browser tab switched

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm using typed.js on my site and I'm having a problem with regards to the typed text animation on the home page slider. The typing animation is synced up when you stay on the page, but as soon as you switch tabs, the typing animation pauses, while the background slider continues to cycle, hence causing the text to be out of sync with the background it relates to. Is there any way to stop the typed animation from pausing when browser tabs are switched and have it continue to cycle with the background slider?

This is the javascript I have for the carousel (using Backstretch) and typed.js

```
        $('bigWrapper').backstretch([
            "img/homeIntro.jpg"
          , "img/videoIntro.jpg"
          , "img/photoIntro.jpg"
          , "img/mixingIntro.jpg"
          , "img/webIntro.jpg"
        ], {fade: 750});
        
        $('bigWrapper').backstretch("pause");
        
        //autotype

        $(".TextHolder2").typed({
            strings: ["Production", "Videography", "Photography", "Audio Engineering", "Web Development"],
            typeSpeed: 30,
            backDelay: 1500,
            loop: true,
            preStringTyped: function(pos, self) {       
                $('bigWrapper').backstretch('show', pos);
            };
        });
```

Comment: For me it's out of sync from the moment it loads.

Comment: Yea that'd happen when it's the first time loading the page. I have to optimize the images in the carousel so it doesn't take as long to load.

Comment: Please add the jquery-backstretch portion to your [mcve], and we can see if we can make get it to do what you want.

Comment: Done, I've tried what you guys suggested down below, but now none of the images load and the text no longer shows.

Comment: take out `duration: 2300, `, it's no longer needed, add a `,` between `loop: true` and `preStringTyped: ...`. Also, if `paused: true` isn't working, then try adding a line directly beneath your backstretch portion that says `$('bigWrapper').backstretch("pause");`

Comment: Still no luck, i've updated my question with the current code I have.

Comment: Take the `;` off of the end of your second-to-last line, and if I read right, your `bigWrapper` is an id, thus it should be `$('#bigWrapper')`.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, the page you're linking to seems to have the `bigWrapper` id set on `<body>`, in which case, you shouldn't need the id, just use `$.backstretch(...)` and it'll apply to `<body>`.

Comment: Noted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of how the browser deals with `setTimeout()`, which typed.js uses. To conserve resources, most browser stop running those async callbacks when you're not focused on the page/tab.

Trying to sync two different timers in a browser is an exercise in futility. Instead, you should treat your carousel (slider) as the master timer and slave typed to it.

See if your carousel plugin has some kind of `next` or `advance` events you can listen for. Then see if you can configure typed to not advance until you tell it to; Basically a delay of infinity. Then, when a `advance` event is fired from your carousel, you can tell typed to `advance` as well. That way they always stay in sync.

You're using [Backstretch](https://github.com/jquery-backstretch/jquery-backstretch) which has an option to start paused.

```
$('whatever').backstretch({
    paused: true
});
```

You can then listen for events on Typed to control when Backstretch transitions. For example, the following (guess) would make backstretch go to the same "frame" as the typed, just as the frame is about to be typed.

```
$('something').typed({
    preStringTyped: function(pos, self) {
        $('whatever').backstretch('show', pos);
    });
});
```

Comment: Personally, I would recommend taking the opposite route, having the background wait to change until the text starts it's next animation.

Comment: I'm using the backstretch plugin and i'm not sure that's possible with this.. I may have to change the plugin.
http://www.jquery-backstretch.com/

Comment: You seem to have put yourself in plugin hell. For this much of a custom "multimedia" experience, you'd be better of building out the elements yourself so can fully control them.

Comment: I think it can be done by setting the `backstretch` to start off `paused`, then use one of `typed`'s hooks (here's a list `onComplete`, `preStringTyped`, `onStringTyped`, `onLastStringBackspaced`, `onTypingPaused`, `onTypingResumed`, `onReset`, `onStop`, `onStart`, `onDestroy`) to trigger `.backstretch("next")` or `.backstretch("show", n)` to show the associated slide.

Comment: I'll add that to the answer.